# How to disable custom checkboxes in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Checkboxes are problematic with the latest Foundation (4.1.6) for many reasons. Is there an easy way to disable Foundation from taking them over? I need the `custom` class in my `form`s for other reasons. How do I get Foundation to leave my HTML checkboxes alone?

Answer (score 3):

I have not encountered a Foundation way of doing this, this is actually the first time I've heard this request.

You can achieve what you want by doing this:

```
// do this after you initialize foundation
$("form.custom").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {            
    $(this).removeClass('hidden-field');
    $(this).next('span.custom.checkbox').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An old post but for anyone trying this currently, there is a very easy way: `data-customforms="disabled"` works on any custom input as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

The minified version of foundation 4 (foundation.min.js) includes foundation.forms.js. What I found to work best is to minify foundation.js manually and use this instead of foundation.min.js. Include foundation.forms.js in your project and remove the [type="checkbox"] selector from line 39.

Before Edit:

```
$('form.custom input[type="radio"],[type="checkbox"]', $(this.scope))
```

After Edit:

```
$('form.custom input[type="radio"], $(this.scope))
```

Only add the parts of foundation that you use i.e. foundation.reveal.js, foundation.abide.js. That will prevent foundation 4 from taking over your form elements.